# Canvas handels disapears when I click on them to change the position of ui objects according to it

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas

I want the canvas handels to be seen when trying to change the position of TetMeshPro like below((for eample I want to align ui object in the middle of my canvas)):

[image]

but when I click on textMeshPro Canvas handles disapear:

[image]

[what I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0bPh.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell you simply have the [**Gizmos**](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GizmosMenu.html) turned off in general.

Simply enable them again by clicking on <kbd>Gizmos</kbd> on top of the SceneView ;)

[image]